# Order-preserving update of a sublist of a list of mutable objects in sublinear time

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists, lists, balanced-search-trees, ordering

### Description

Say I have a source list like: `["a","b","c","d"]` and want to run a capitalization filter so if I change, `"b"` to `"B"`, my derived list looks like `["B"]`.  Next, if I change my source list's `"d"` to `"D"`, the derived list should look like `["B","D"]`.

Is it possible to make the insertions and removals in the derived list, while maintaining order, in faster than $O(n)$ time, $n$ being the size of the list?

Finally, I'd like to be able to **know the index of where the insertion or removal takes place** in the derived list in faster than $O(n)$ time.

### An idea that doesn't work

I could keep the derived list in a tree, sorted by the source index. This way, when I needed to insert my item in derived tree-list, it would take $O(log n)$.  However, I would not be able to know that index of that insertion without walking the entire tree.

Thanks for your help!

### Problem Statement

- Let $S$ be an ordered list
- Let $Si.filterProperty$ be $true$ for some elements in $S$
- Let $F$ be an ordered list of all elements in $S$ where $Si.filterProperty$ is true

Let $T(i)$ be a function that:

- Sets $Si.filterProperty$ to $true$
- Inserts $Si$ into $F$, ordered in the same fashion as $S$
- Returns the index in $F$ where $Si$ was inserted

**Can $T$ and its side effects be faster than $O(n)$?**

Any list-like data structures can be used within these constraints:

- Insertion and side effects of insertion are faster than $O(n)$
- We must know the index of the newly inserted item into $F$

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, or what task you are trying to make run fast.  I also don't understand the filter (why isn't the derived list `["A","B","C","D"]`? that's what you get after capitalizing every element of the input list -- so it sounds like you also have a selection operator you haven't told us about).  Finally, what have you tried?  For instance, do you know about balanced binary search trees?  If you store the derived list in such a data structure, insertions and deletions take $O(\lg n)$ time.  So: Can you edit the question to clarify?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying so solve? This has the smell of "actually, what you want to do is...". In particular, does $F$ do be exist explicitly? What properties does $F$ have to have, API-wise?

Comment: If you keep $S$ in a balanced binary tree, you can do insertion in
$\log n$ time. You can keep in each node of the tree a count of the
number of elements below it so that the current rank of any element in
$S$ can also be known in $\log n$ time. Finally we also keep in each
node a count of the elements of $F$ below it, so that we can also
compute the rank in $F$ in $\log n$ time. This seems to meet your
requirement in a fairly standard way. So I am wondering whether you
have more constraints regarding the use of $F$. In particular, I am
not sure what $n$ is supposed to be.

Comment: D.W - a "filter" is something function that includes or doesn't include an item based on some condition.  A mapping would produce `["A","B","C","D"]`.  Yes, I know about balanced binary trees.  But as I mentioned, this wouldn't give me O(n) to know the index.

Comment: @Raphael -  Thanks for cleaning up my question.  For context, I'm the author of a JS open source library.  I want users to be able to give me some form of F that I can then use to trigger live-binding updates.  For example, http://todomvc.com/examples/canjs/ might load all todos, but render a "filtered" projection of all the completed todos.  I want to update that projection faster than O(n).

Comment: @babou Thanks for the suggestion.  How could I maintain the "count of the number of elements below it"?  Wouldn't I need to update every node's count if I was inserting as the first item?

Comment: @JustinMeyer For each insertion, increment the count of any node that is traversed by one.

Comment: @JustinMeyer I give you an answer below. I think it should solve your problem. Note
that when you insert a new node/element, you will modify counts only
on the path from the tree root to the position of the new node. It is
entirely local.  My previous comments may have been a bit cryptic
because I first understood you wanted something more complex. This is
actually very simple to implement.

Comment: => Justin Meyer : @jandjorgensen told me my answer was the right approach
for your need, though you may want to adapt it to another kind of self
ba;ancing binary search tree. Indeed, the choice of the type of tree
depends on usage statistics, as AVL trees are faster when look-up
dominates over tree modifications, while red-black trees are otherwise
faster. So, did it solve your problem?

Comment: => Justin Meyer : @jandjorgensen I added a new answer with same complexity      that can handle dynamically changing source list and any number of filtered lists. Hoping it meets your need. But writing pseudo code would make little sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*At the time of writing I was not absolutely sure what the problem
was. This lead to a more general [second answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43447/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-filtered-list-up-to-date-with-changes-in-the-source-l/44520#44520). See details in
discussion at the end of this answer.*

Apparently, the "idea that does not work" does not work because you do
not know the index of an element $S_i$ in $F$ organized as a tree.

This is what is addressed here. The problem is restated for clarity, as your statement of it is a bit hard to follow.

### Restatement of the problem:

Given a set $S$ with an order relation, maintain an ordered list $F$
where elements of $S$ can be inserted or removed, and such that the
index of an element in $F$ is returned when the element is inserted.

Actually, the solution will do more, as it is possible to access any
element of $F$ given its index, or to retrieve the index given an
element of $F$. All operations are in time $\log n$.

### Solution:

You keep the ordered derived list $F$ in a self-balancing binary
tree. I checked with [AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), but other types (such as red-black
trees) should work as well. In each node $N$ of the tree you keep a
count $\text{weight}(N)$ of the number of elements of $F$ in the subtree
rooted in $N$, node $N$ included.

This can be done by updating weight counts as you walk down from the
root of the AVL tree for $F$ to reach the place for the insertion or deletion.
Then, during the retracing phase that rebalances the tree, when
needed, you also update the weight counts according to the
rebalancing.  That only add constant cost to each elementary step,
thus does not change the $\log n$ time complexity of the algorithm.

Hence it is easy to use this weight to compute in $\log n$ time the
index of an element of the list $F$ when accessing it, either on the
way down from the AVL tree root, or by walking up to the root when
accessing the element directly.

The index is computed on the fly by adding the weights of all the immediate
siblings on the left of the path from the AVL tree root to the
concerned element of $F$.

Conversely, it is easy to find in $\log n$ time an element of $F$ from
its (left to right) index by walking down from the root and leaving
enough elements on the left.

### Computing the index of $S_i$ in $F$ using weights:

Recall that the weight of a node $N$ is the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at $N$, node $N$ included.

Computing the index of $S_i$ from the weights in the tree is precisely
done as follows: you simply do a search for $S_i$ in the standard way of
binary search trees, with a modification to compute the index. Below
is a pseudo-code recursive version, [adapted from the searching algorithm in
wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Searching). It raises an exception if $S_i$ is not in the AVL tree, and
the index count start at 0 for the first element. To have the count start at 1, the first return statement should be `return node.left.weight+1`.

```
function Find-recursive(S_i, node):  // call initially with node = root
    if node = Null then
        raise Key_Not_Found
    else if node.key = S_i then
        if node.left = Null then return 0
        else return node.left.weight
    else if key < node.key then
        return Find-recursive(key, node.left)
    else
        if node.left = Null then return Find-recursive(key, node.right)+1
        else return Find-recursive(key, node.right)+node.left.weight+1
```

When the path from the root goes to the right daughter, that means
that all nodes in the left daugther subtree, plus the current node, precede
$S_i$, and have to be added to whatever other predecessors will be
found while searching in the right daughter subtree.

I do not give here the modifications of the insertion and deletion code necessary to update the weight count, as this is a bit too long for an answer here, and not so hard to do.

### About the question, and the two proposed answers

The precise specification of the problem took some time to agree upon.

This **first answer** to the question was written on the basis of an
initial specification that did not mention explicitly that the source list $S$
could be modified dynamically, by insertion or deletion, thus possibly
inducing a similar modification in the filtered list $F$.

The elements of list $S$ are mutable objects and have a *filter-property*
$P_F$ that may be true or false depending on operations performed on
an element. The purpose of the question is to maintain a sublist $F$ of
elements $s\in S$ such that $P_F(s)$, similarly ordered, such that the
rank in $F$ of an element $s\in S$ is known when it in inserted in $F$ due to
a mutation.

I assume in this first answer here that the list $S$ is constant,
except for changes to its mutable elements. Thus on may see the list
$S$ as a set (of list elements), totally ordered by the order of the
list, and that relative order of two elements can be checked in
constant time $O(1)$, for example by attaching its $S$-list rank to
each element.

In a [much later comment to this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43447/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-filtered-list-up-to-date-with-changes-in-the-source-l/43512#comment90724_43512), the author of the question
made it clear that he also wanted to be able to modify the list $S$
with insertion or deletion of elements. This more complex question is
addressed  separately in a **[second answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43447/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-filtered-list-up-to-date-with-changes-in-the-source-l/44520#44520)**.

**Why keep both answers?** The first algorithm here is slightly more
efficient as all operations can be performed in time $O(\log|F|)$,
while the more general algorithm (second answer) requires time
$O(\log|S|)$. With a constant ratio $|F|/|S|$, the difference is only
an additive constant $\log|S|-\log|F|$. However this constant is to be
compared to a logarithmic complexity $\log|F|$, which may not be very
large itself. And this complexity is that of elementary operations on
a data structure, to be repeated often in larger algorithms. So this
apparently negligible difference may have a measurable impact on
performance of a larger algorithm using the structure.

To see it numerically, assume that $|S|=256$ and $|F|=16$. Then
$\log|S|=8$ and $\log|F|=4$, which give a performance ratio of $2$,
to which one should add that the structure of the more general
algorithm may be more costly to maintain.

Comment: You restated the problem very well. Think you could write out how the index is computed from the weight? If I beat you to it I'll just propose an edit--just probably best for a beta SE site to state everything in detail where possible.

Comment: @jandjorgensen I have stuff to finish right now. If you want to give it a try. I wish the OP would react as it is not clear that he does not want more.

Comment: I'm working with him on this--this is a good approach.

Comment: I see. So talking to you or him is about same. Well, as you wish. I was waiting for reactions. It is too often the case that I do some time consuming work on a question and the poster never shows up again. What is important too is updating weight on insertion and deletion (if you change your mind about completion of a "todo").

Comment: I'm going to put in another answer using a RB-tree approach with pseudocode, unless you'd like to community wiki your post and I can organize it into a larger collaborative solution.

Comment: It is probably better not to mix too much the various approaches. Very long answers are hard to keep organized.

Comment: @babou what is meant by "set S with an order relation"?  If it means that there is a sort order applied to the list, that is incorrect.  ["c","a","b","d"] would be as valid S as ["a","b","c","d"] would be.

Comment: @babou I don't think this is an answer because I'm unable to know where to insert a new item in F.  The placement of a new item in F is determined by its index in S.  

For example, if I had S = `[z, J, a, X, C, K]` so F = `[J, X, C, K]`, and inserted W in between X and C, how would I determine where to insert W in `F` without also keeping the source indexes also in F and updating them (in N time)?

Comment: @JustinMeyer As I recall, you start with a list of object, and you want their order to be respected troughout the dynamic filtering. The set S is the the collection of elements of your original unfiltered list (distinguishing occurrences, if some are equal). The order is the order imposed by the list. So, with ["c","a","b","d"], the sort order is "c"<"a"<"b"<"d". The point is that the Binary Search Tree is usually built on an order, so I assert its existence. But it is precisely what you want: the list order. I am not suggesting sorting the source list. Does this answer your question?

Comment: But the source list has no "permanently" defined order other than how people add items to it.  They can add or remove items in arbitrary order. 

With that consideration, I don't understand how your solution lets me know where to insert a new item in F.  I just posted an answer that might help explain where I'm coming from.

Comment: @JustinMeyer Actually my answer is an answer because inserting a new element
W in the source list was not part of your specification. Nevertheless
it can be done. There are various ways one may consider, depending a
bit on what are the parameters and constraints. If you actually need
it, I can suggest some solution.

Comment: @babou Yes, this is an answer if the list never adds items.  Unfortunately, I need to solve that problem, do you recommend that I create a new question?

Comment: @JustinMeyer Let me check whether it requires real development, or if
I can come up with a simple adjustment of the existing solution. I
think I have a simple one that multiplies the complexity by $\log|S|$,
but I do not know whether that is acceptable for your application. But
what is your spec regarding modifications of S? (BTW did you get my
mail) - P.S. I just discovered you had added an answer. That is what I
had in mind: a balanced tree for S to compute indexes on the fly.

Comment: @JustinMeyer A simpler solution, which should work in just $O(\log|S|)$ for all
operations is to keep a single Binary Search Tree (BST), were node are
marked (or identifiable) when they belong to F. You keep two counts on
the node, corresponding to the weight of the subtree with respect to S
and to F, so that you can compute the rank in both lists. Does that
seem OK to you? I can write it doen in more details ... but not right now (bed time).

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a data structure for a set of integers with a rank operation.  There are a number of published solutions with performance as good as O(1) on both queries and updates, for instance [this recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3045).

These structures are fairly intricate, but generally they break the elements into blocks and maintain a summary rank for each block to use as a starting point.  It's not much different from using a tree with leaf counts, but the space can be considerably smaller.

[This blog post](http://alexbowe.com/rrr/) describes the basic ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that seems to work in *O(log N x log N)* time.  However, I'm betting there's an answer in *O(log N)* time.

In short, I keep a **T** self-balancing tree that reflects the source list **S**. It keeps track of indexes using the "left count" approach @babou suggested. Every node also knows about its parent.

I also keep an **F** self-balancing tree that represents the filtered result, but with references to its symmetric nodes in  **T**. This also uses "left count" on each node.

Together, it works as follows.  Say **S** looks like:

```
S = [Z,b,c,e, f, G]
```

**T** might look like:

```
                   {v: c,LC: 2}
{v: Z, LC: 0}                      {v: f, LC: 1}
      {v: b, LC: 0}         {v: e, LC: 0}   {v: G, LC: 0}
```

where v is the value, LC is the left count.

And the output **F** would look like:

```
{v: Z, LC: 0, NR: Z}
     {v: G, LC: 0, NR: G}
```

where NR is a reference to it's parallel node in **T**.  At this point, F has all the capitalized letters `[Z, G]` and we know the indexes of each.

Now lets see what happens if I insert `D` in-between `c` and `e`.

First, we know the index 3 at which this happens and can insert it into and rotate **T** accordingly.  T will look like:

```
                        {v: D,LC: 3}
        {v: c,LC: 1}                    {v: f, LC: 1}
{v: Z, LC: 0}   {v: b, LC: 0}       {v: e, LC: 0}   {v: G, LC: 0}
```

Once **T** has been set, I can do a binary search and insert in **F**.  I'd start at the root node `{v: Z, LC: 0, NR: Z}`, use the node reference to find the corresponding node in **T** and use the node in **T** to calculate the index in *O(log n)* time.  I'd have to repeat this *O(log n)* times.

Answer (score 1):

## An $O(\log n)$ solution for dynamically changing source list

### The problem

In a previous answer, I assumed that $S$ was a fixed list of elements,
considered as a set ordered by the place of elements in the list. Only some property of the elements was supposed to be modifiable. The
problem was to maintain another ordered list $F$ where elements of $S$, filtered for that property,
could be inserted or removed, and such that the rank index of an element in
$F$ was returned when the element was inserted.

Assuming the list to be fixed was essential because, by precomputing
the rank index of each element in the list, if was possible to check
the order of two elements in unit time $O(1)$ by comparing their
ranks.

**In a later comment, the poster of the question indicated that in
addition to the stated specification of the problem, the list $S$ itself can
be modified by insertion and deletion.** Then there may no longer be a
way to check the order of two elements in unit time. It is possible to
maintain a rank index dynamically, as shown below, but computing it
has a cost $O(\log|S|)$, so that the whole complexity of each
operation is multiplied by that value, thus having a complexity
$O(\log|F|\times\log|S|)$, or, to simplify in $O(\log^2 n)$ where
$n=|S|$ is the size of the source list.

So I propose here a structure for implementing both lists $S$ and $F$ in such a
way that:

- the order in $S$ is preserved for both,
- elements can be inserted or removed anywhere in $S$,
- any element of $S$ that is modified to satisfy a property $P_F$ can
  be inserted in $F$, or removed if it no longer satisfies $P_F$,
- for any element, it is possible to find its rank index in $S$ and in $F$
- all operations being executed with a cost $O(\log |S|)$.

Furthermore the technique can be extended to handle simultaneously
several lists $F_1, \ldots F_i\ldots$ each corresponding to a
different property $P_i$.

Finally, I propose a technique to maintain a simple linked list of
the elements in $F$, so that they can be listed in time $O(|F|)$
independently of the size of the source list $S$.

### The base structure

The idea is to use a unique [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) (BST)
such as an [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)). This tree is first used to
implement the list $S$. This may seem strange as there is no a priori
order to the elements of the list, and their order is determined only
by arbitrary insertions and deletions. So the insertion procedure has
to be changed, in a fairly trivial way, as you choose to insert a new
node after some given node of the existing structure (inducing the
order as a consequence, since there is none a priori) and rebalance
the tree accordingly.

To every node $N$, you add a weight $W_S$ which is the number of elements
of $S$ in the subtree rooted in $N$, actually the number of nodes of
that subtree. This weight can be updated when inserting of deleting a
node without changing the $O(\log |S|)$ cost of the
operation. Furthermore, the weight can be used to compute the rank index of
a node in $O(\log |S|)$ time, or to retrieve a node from its rank in
the same time.

The rank index is computed on the fly by adding the weights of all the
immediate siblings on the left of the path from the tree root to the
concerned element of $S$. Their number is $O(\log |S|)$.

Conversely, it is easy to find in logn time an element of F from its
(left to right) index by walking down from the root and leaving enough
elements on the left.

### Implmenting the list $F$

To implement the list $F$, one simply marks as such the nodes of the
tree that contain an element of $F$. Actually they can be simply
identified by testing he property $P_F$, when that test is cheap (i.e. at worst $O(1)$)

To be able to compute the index of an element in the list $F$, we add to
each node $N$ a second weight $W_F$, which is the number of elements
of $F$ in the subtree rooted in $N$. This weight is updated exactly
like the previous one $W_S$. It is also used in the same way to get
the index of a node in $F$ or to find a node in $F$ from its rank.
There is a little subtlety in the latter, as, after leaving enough
nodes on the left, we may have to search for the next subtree with a
non zero weight $W_F$, since that weight can be zero for some nodes.

All this can be achieved in time $O(\log|S|)$ for each operation.

**Enumerating $F$**

If you want to enumerate in order all the elements of the list $F$,
this can be done by enumerating the elements of $S$ by walking the
tree, and filtering out those that are not in $F$. That take time $O(|S|)$.

But, it may be the case that the list $S$ is much larger than $F$, and
it would be convenient to enumerate easily the elements of $F$ without
this overhead, in time $O(|F|)$.

This can be done by maintaining in each node a link $L_F$, which is
NIL if the node is not in $F$, or is the last node in $F$, and which
points to the next node in $F$ when it is a node in $F$ other than the
last one.

These pointers have to be maintained every time a node is inserted in
$F$ or removed from it. But it is easily done in time $O(\log|S|)$
like other operations, thus not modifying the complexity. It is
obviously  possible since we can find the rank $r$ of a node $N$ inserted in
$F$, and we can find the nodes preceeding and following $N$ from their
rank $r-1$ and $r+1$, each  in time $O(\log|S|)$. But there are faster ways to do it.

### Using several filtered lists

The means for implementing the filtered list $F$ are built on top of
the self-balancing binary search tree representing the list $S$, but
they interfere in no way with the operations on that tree concerning
$S$. Thus it is possible to implement in the same way as many filtered
lists as may be needed, corresponding to different filtering
predicate.

**Note:** The above sketches the algorithmic technique. Writing the
whole thing is pseudo-code is far beyond what could be considered
reasonable in a normal answer.